# iOS tab bar confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created the code for iPhone 5 before using storyboard and want to add support for iPhone6 and 6+..

There is Tabbar controller of height 49 and have 3 tab icons. That's all perfectly working on iphone 5 without any issue..Looks good tab bar..

What should I do for iPhone 6/6+.. I have put background image on tabbar controller for iPhone 5 and also 3 icons.. Now I have to change any code or any storyboard setting to make app compatible with `iPhone 6/6+`?

I have created the background image (tabbar) and 3 icon for `iphone6/6+` through photoshop, so it is little bit big compare to iphone 5 background image and icons.. I am correct with this setup ? should I create bigger image size for background image and icons for iphone6/6+ or stay with old size of background image and icon size (iphone 5)?

I am testing with code ios-7,8,9.

Comment: What have you used Autolayout constraints or Size classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]You need 3 kinds of images in Image Assets because in terms of Scaling or Pixels There are 3 kinds of Apple Devices (iPhone and iPad) that is

Normal device which terms to 1 pixel = 1 point@1x (Older iPhone and iPad devices)

Retina device which terms to 4 pixels = 1 point@2x (iPhone 5+)

Retina iPhone6 and iPad which terms to 9 pixels = 1 point@3x (iPhone6+)

Thus for providing same image in 3 scales iOS decides which image to show for which devices.Hope could help you understand this.

Follow this link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Ok.thanks for reply..so i need to 3 differnt size of image iphone 5,6,6+ for tab bar icon.. how can i set within story board or i have to code manually something like if phone 5 ... else if iphone6 ... etc etc.. and other question is iphone 5 and iphone 6 both have @2x.png formate so how can i set which image for iphone 5 or others for iphone 6, if do it within storyboard?

Comment: No.... Go to Images.xcassets in folder hierarchy and paste 1x,2x,3x images and use just image name in story board and program (like u r using xyz@1x.png xyz@2x.png xyz@3x.png images and to use these in program u have to use there name xyz instead of xyz@1x.png and xcode will pic 1x,2x,3x according to the screen size )

Comment: I follow your steps but after that I got  in iphone 5 its working perfectly but iphone 6  have issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vw3rcpm9doz0quj/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-11%20at%207.15.05%20pm.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd997s0tapuf1s3/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-11%20at%207.15.34%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: Please check the given two links of one for iphone 5 and others is iphone 6... and other question may be helpfull to undestand each other question : tabbarcontroller image hight and width are different for iphone5/6.. iphone 5: 650x49 and iphone 6: 750x60...so is this correct or i am wrong?